# How to open MediaRecorder file and send it throw socket communication

Tags: android, python, sockets, android-studio, mediarecorder

I am trying to send record from an application using sockets.

```
private Button play,record,stop;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputFile;
private Thread thread;
private String ADDRESSIP = "10.0.0.8";
private int PORT = 5565;
private PrintWriter pw;
Socket s;
private String respone = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    record = (Button)findViewById(R.id.record);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    play.setEnabled(true);

    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                myAudioRecorder.start();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                //make something
            }

            record.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.reset();
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder = null;
            record.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            play.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Recorder Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    //open socket
                    try
                    {
                        s = new Socket(ADDRESSIP , PORT);
                        System.out.println("connected");
                        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
//Have to send 2 for the server so he will know that he needs to open .3mp file

                        pw.write('2');
                        pw.flush();

                        //sending the file to the server here
                        File myFile = new File(outputFile);
                        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                        pw.write(fis.read());
                        pw.flush();

                        pw.close();
                    }catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

outPutFile is the path of the mediaRecorder object, so I tried to open that as a regular file and then send the file in bytes to the server.

The code in the server is in Python:

```
if received == 2: #connection with the application
        conn.send("Return, now continue...")

        condition_need_to_take_photo.acquire()
        fp = open('audio_file.mp3' , 'wb')
        while True:
            strng = conn.recv(1024)
            if b'ENDED' in strng and not strng:
                break
            fp.write(strng)
        labels = Speech_To_Text.Text_From_Audio('audio_file.3mp')
        #audio=take the audio file
        print labels
        condition_need_to_take_photo.notify()
        condition_need_to_take_photo.release()
```

Please help me understand how may I transfer the data from the application to the server

Thank you

Comment: Well could you first tell what the problem is with your code?

Comment: Actually I can't find the problem, but it doesn't work

Comment: It does nkt wirk is nit a good problem description. You should try better.